# Battery charger circuit confusion - drive and compensation

Tags: analog, battery-charging, buck, driver, compensation

I'm building something that is going to have Li-Ion batteries so I'm trying to learn how a battery charger actually works. I've been looking over the datasheets for the BQ2000 and the BQ2954. I will say preemptively that I am only looking at ICs which have through-hole variants on purpose. I'm seeing the obvious overlap is that the example designs in the datasheet are just modified buck converters.

Here is the example from the BQ2954 datasheet
[image: Here is the example from the BQ2954 datasheet.]

The actual current path to the battery goes through a PNP using drive circuitry that I somewhat understand to keep on and off times fast.

Here is the example from the BQ2000 datasheet
[image: Here is the example from the BQ2000 datasheet.]

It's similar but there is no  pullup from PNP base to emitter. I simulated this and it works, and I somewhat understand the idea: NPN for a quick discharge, but I do not understand this BQ2000 version. How is the PNP base being biased before any control happens? What exactly is the diode-capacitor doing? I know this is more Buck control theory than battery charging but that brings me to my second question:

The BQ2954 has two external pins for compensation: Vcomp and Icomp. The BQ2000 has no such pins. Is there either:
A way to apply this compensation to the IC that does not have these pins?
or
A more generic IC type that I could be using instead of these specific battery charging ICs?

It seems like the only benefit is basically an integrated time-out that I could potentially do in software with a microcontroller.
Any experience using battery charging ICs is helpful.